# How to assign each loop data to multiple columns in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a csv file which has 5 URLs in it under one column named 'URLS'. Using urllib I'm scraping the data of each URL and splitting the data into words and appending it to empty list and creating dataframe using that empty list. Now the problem is all the data scraped from 5 URLs are in one column only but I want to assign each URLs data to each column. How to do that?

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
url_list = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Desktop/websites.csv")
urls = url_list['URLS']



def addhttp():

    empty=[]
    for url in urls:
    final_url = 'http://' + url
    try:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(final_url).read().decode('utf-8')
        text = get_text(html)
        extracted_data = text.split()
        refined_data = []
        SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~0123456789'
        for i in extracted_data:
            if i not in SYMBOLS:
                refined_data.append(i)

        print("\n", "$" * 50, "HEYAAA we got arround: ", len(refined_data), " of keywords! Here are they: ",
              "$" * 50, "\n")
        empty.append(refined_data)


    except:
        pass

    df = pd.DataFrame(empty)
    df.to_csv('websitesdata.csv', index=False)


Original Output:

0
This
website
is
all
about
learning
python
-
-
-
-
not
serving
any
more
etc


Expected Output:

website:1  website:2  website:3    
This         This      This
website       is       website
is           another    not
all          website   serving
about        where      any
learning     you       more
python       can
             learn
             python
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to save the data instead of a list.
In this partcular case [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) would be useful.

```
from collections import defaultdict
refined_data = defaultdict(list)
.
.
.
for url in urls:
.
.
.
    for i in extracted_data:
    .
    .
    .
        refined_data[url].append(i)
```

.
   .
   .

This should yield you the desired result

Comment: I'm not getting exactly. Can you define it some more.

Comment: where should I mention the code **refined_data = defaultdict(list)** inside function or outside of function also what is __list__  should contain?

Comment: instead of your empty=[] use refined_data

Comment: Still I'm getting data in one column only but I want multiple columns.

Comment: can you please correct the code in question if possible as I'm confused.

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be callable or None